# Does SnowflakeIO Connector in Java support Flink?

Tags: java, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-beam

As per the document on https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/snowflake/#running-main-command-with-pipeline-options, I can only see DirectRunner and DataflowRunner, and I have tested the DirectRunner which is working fine. Just wonder if it supports Flink officially. Any comments are welcomed. Thanks.

I tested DirectRunner which is working.